# space is not recognized - Other ascii chars are

Tags: c

I don't know what is going on here, but i can't read spaces (?)

It's happening all over the code, take this as an example:

Simple function to count ' ' (white spaces):

```
int countS (char s[]){
    int i,k;

    i=0;
    k=0;

    while(s[i]!='\0'){
        if((int) s[i]==32){
            k++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return k;
}
```

I've tried casting and:

```
int countS (char s[]){
    int i,k;

    i=0;
    k=0;

    while(s[i]!='\0'){
        if(s[i]==' '){
            k++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return k;
}
```

Not working at all.

EDIT:

i am sorry for the "not working at all", usually i do include the output in my answers, i was a bit tired.

The output was 0;

Comment: How are you determining that this isn't working?

Comment: Try a `printf("<%s>\n", s);` to see what `s` actually is.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Show the calling code and the input.

Comment: Could it be that you're obtaining the string using `scanf` with a `"%s"` format? That reads a space-delimited word, not a line. Meanwhile, try `countS("foo bar baz")`; it should return 2. (BTW, your second version is much better; in the first, the cast is unnecessary, and there's no point in writing `32` rather than `' '` to represent a space character.)

Comment: Both versions of the function work correctly.

Comment: You also need to explain clearly what "Not working at all" means. Does it return `0`? Does it crash?

Comment: step through with a debugger

Comment: what string you inputted?

Comment: You can simplify your code:

`int countS (char s[]){

    int k=0;

 for(int i=0; s[i]!='\0'; i++) 
  s[i]==' '?k++:k;
    
 return k;
}`

Comment: Modify the code to show the code that is not working, then we can help your fix your problem. These functions are not the problem.

Comment: The issue was related to the scanf, you were right Keith.

Comment: @DmitriyOlhovsky I'd consider that worse, it's hard to explain the `k` in the `:k;` bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works right out of the box. Copied and pasted your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Put your code here */

int main()
{
    char str[] = "This is the time for all good men to come to the aid of the country! ";
    printf("%d\n", countS(str) );
}
```

Output:

```
16
```

Comment: How is this an answer? I already commented that both versions of OP's function work.

Comment: Modify the code sample to show the code that is not working. Then we can tell you what is wrong with it.

Comment: @WeatherVane "your code actually does work", plus an example, is a valid answer to the question "Why isn't this working".   If OP updates the question, then the answer can be updated too.

Comment: @MattMcNabb the comment I left here was the last of 3 after pointing out consecutive errors in the original poor answer, which was edited within 5 minutes of the post, and so not shown in its history. And it's still not an answer that can't be put in a comment.

Comment: @WeatherVane site policy is that answers should not be posted as comments